# Scalable invocation of Spark MLlib 1.6 predictive model w/a single data record

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, apache-spark-mllib

I have a predictive model (Logistic Regression) built in Spark 1.6   that has been  saved to disk for later reuse with new data records. I want to invoke it with multiple clients with each  client passing in  single data record. It seems that using a Spark job to run single records through would have way too much overhead and would not be  very scalable (each invocation will only pass in a single set of 18 values). The MLlib API to load a saved model  requires the  Spark Context though so am looking for suggestions of how to do this in a scalable way.  Spark Streaming with Kafka input comes to mind (each client request  would be written to a Kafka topic). Any thoughts on this idea or alternative suggestions ?

Answer (score 1):

Non-distributed (in practice it is majority) models from `o.a.s.mllib` don't require an active `SparkContext` for single item predictions. If you check [API docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionModel) you'll see that `LogisticRegressionModel` provides `predict` method with signature `Vector => Double`. It means you can serialize model using standard Java tools, read it later and perform prediction on local `o.a.s.mllib.Vector` object.

Spark also provides [a limited PMML support](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-pmml-model-export.html) (not for logistic regression) so you share your models with any other library which supports this format.

Finally non-distributed models are usually not so complex. For linear models all you need is intercept, coefficients and some basic math functions and linear algebra library (if you want a decent performance).

`o.a.s.ml` models are slightly harder to handle but there are some external tools which try to address that. You can check related discussion on the developers list, ([Deploying ML Pipeline Model](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/Deploying-ML-Pipeline-Model-td18149.html)) for details.

For distributed models there is really no good workaround. You'll have to start a full job on distributed dataset one way or another.